# Question on probability - A and B toss a pair of coins alternatively

Tags: probability

A and B toss a pair of coins alternatively. One who gets two heads together will win the game. If A starts the game, find probability of B winning the game.

Can anyone guide me how to approach this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with Pascal distribution (or Negative binomial distribution)?

Comment: no, but if it is required, i can see that principles and try doing it. Please advise which are the principles I need to study for such problems . thanks

Comment: Have you every looked at "first step analysis"? Consider what the first flip of $A$ is and move from there.

Comment: Ok, I think this would make it worse. I'm sorry.
I think you got this problem from some class in Markov Chains (or stochastic phenomena). If this is case, you just need to notice that this process is happening $\{0,1,2\}^2$, which a 9 element set, with all transitions wither 0 or $1/2$.

Comment: @Tom , I tried. If P(A winning first toss) = 1/4

Comment: You're probably intended to use Craps principle.

Comment: @Guilherme Thompson , I was learning binomial theorem and this is a problem I created my own. I was thinking of various problems and in  a discussion with my friend, we thought of such a situation. Never though this was so complex. In my studies, I never even heard of principles mentioned in these comments. Now looking into one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive method:  Let $p$ be the probability that $A$ wins this game (so the answer you want is $1-p$.)

Consider the first toss:  Either $A$ wins (probability $\frac 14$) or the turn passes to $B$, at which point $A$ will clearly have a $1-p$ probability of victory.  Thus we get the recursion:  $$p=\frac 14\;1+\frac 34\;(1-p)\;\;\implies\;\;p=1-\frac 34\;p\;\;\implies\;\;p=\frac 47$$

Hence the answer you want is $\frac 37$

Comment: am now confused. Your approach and @probablyme 's approach , both seems right to me.

Comment: The approach of @probalyme is fine but the calculation is flawed.  The probability that $B$ wins in the first round is $\frac 3{16}$, not $\frac 1{16}$ ($A$ must lose, prob. $\frac 34$, and $B$ must win, prob $\frac 14$).

Comment: ah, got it. thanks

Comment: Just intuitively, the answer $\frac 15$ is far too low.  The answer has to be nearer $\frac 12$.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and @probablyme 's answer. Unfortunate that i don;t have option to select two best answers:(

Comment: Intuition becomes clear if you work with odds (instead of probabilities) of $A$ winnings the game: $=1+odds(\frac 1 4)=\frac 4 3$.

Comment: @lulu, while going into the details, I am confused about the following part.  How probability of A is 1-p when the turn goes to B. can u please explain thanks

Comment: Say $A$ misses on the first attempt, so it becomes $B's$ turn.  At that point it is just as if the game was starting afresh, only with $B$ as the first player.  That means that $B$ will now win with probability $p$, hence that $A$ will win with probability $1-p$ (from this point).

Comment: oh yes, got it. thanks a lot for clearing the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

> One who gets two heads together will win the game.

I going to assume this means that Player A takes a turn, flips twice and has to get $HH$ to win. Otherwise, it would be Player B's turn, and they alternate like that. Let $\mathcal A = \{\text{A wins in first turn}\}$, and $\mathcal B = \{\text{B wins in first turn}\}$. For $\mathcal B$, it can happen in three disjoint ways, $\{HTHH, THHH, TTHH\}$. Therefore
$$P(\mathcal B) = P(HTHH)+P(THHH)+P(TTHH) = \frac{3}{16}.$$Then using craps principle, 
$$P(\text{B wins}) = \frac{P(\mathcal B)}{P(\mathcal B)+P(\mathcal A)} = \frac{3/16}{3/16+1/4} = \frac{3}{7}. $$

Comment: The players alternate turns. I don't think one plays through and the other only looks.

Comment: So A flips once, then B flips once, then A flips once... like that?

Comment: This is what I got. As I commented, this is a Markov Chain in $\{0,1,2\}^2$, with a very sparse P-matrix.

Comment: Really? It sounds like the scenario I described. I agree with what you say about the chain, but I don't think the scenario is as you describe. After all, the title says A and B flip a "pair of coins". I'll gladly retract my answer if this is not the case.

Comment: @probablyme, your assumption is right.  Player A takes a turn, flips twice and has to get HH to win.

Comment: "A and B toss a pair of coins alternatively.". My bad, I understood something else by the enunciate. I agree with your result then.

Comment: Note:  the probability that $B$ wins in the first round is $\frac 3{16}$ not $\frac 1{16}$ as you have written.

Comment: @lulu Omg, thank you! I should not respond while tired. :(

Comment: @probablyme  I know the feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Can we also approach and solve it as follows?

P(A wins in first toss) = 1/4

P(A does not win in First)*P(B does not win in second)*P(A wins in third)
=3/4*3/4*1/4

...

Then sum of the infinite series?

Comment: Almost, remember, you said you want the event that B wins. So you would be adding the cases at B wins in first turn + B wins in second turn+... For the first case, it would be $P(\text{B wins in first round}) = P(\text{A does not win in first})\cdot P(\text{B wins in first turn})$. Then you add up the infinite series. This should agree with my answer.

Comment: @probablyme thanks. otherwise, 1 - sum of the  infinite series I got, right?